# is any one good enough to help get this working?

Tags: codeigniter

I have four tables I need to join in query build

```
    function get_debtors( ) {

    $this->db->select('invoice.student_id as STUDENT_ID,student.name AS 
                       STUDENT_NAME,section.name  AS CLASS,
                       invoice.description AS DESCRIPTION, 
                       invoice.amount AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, 
                       invoice.amount_owed  AS AMOUNT_OWED, 
                       parent.name AS PARENT_NAME, 
                       parent.email AS PARENT_EMAIL, 
                       parent.phone AS PARENT_PHONE, 
                       parent.address AS PARENT_ADDRESS,  
                       invoice.status AS STATUS');

    $this->db->from('invoice , student , parent , section ');

    $this->db->join('student  ', 'student.student_id = invoice.student_id');

    $this->db->join('parent ', 'parent.parent_id = student.parent_id, 'left'');

    $this->db->join('section  ', 'section.section_id = student.section_id','left');

    $this->db->where('invoice.status', 'debtor'); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: you used extra one single `'` quotation after `left'` in this line `$this->db->join('parent ', 'parent.parent_id = student.parent_id, 'left'');`

Comment: use only invoice table in from $this->db->from('invoice '); Other table will be joined as per condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If there is still any error than post the error also here.

```
function get_debtors( ) 
{

    $this->db->select('invoice.student_id as STUDENT_ID,student.name AS 
                       STUDENT_NAME,section.name  AS CLASS,
                       invoice.description AS DESCRIPTION, 
                       invoice.amount AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, 
                       invoice.amount_owed  AS AMOUNT_OWED, 
                       parent.name AS PARENT_NAME, 
                       parent.email AS PARENT_EMAIL, 
                       parent.phone AS PARENT_PHONE, 
                       parent.address AS PARENT_ADDRESS,  
                       invoice.status AS STATUS');

    $this->db->from('invoice');

    $this->db->join('student  ', 'student.student_id = invoice.student_id');

    $this->db->join('parent ', 'parent.parent_id = student.parent_id', 'left');

    $this->db->join('section  ', 'section.section_id = student.section_id','left');

    $this->db->where('invoice.status', 'debtor'); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```